# Decoding Passwords stored my spring secuirty in a .NET C# Web Application

Tags: c#, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, grails

I have a Web application with Spring Security and Grails. The Database I use is MySql. I wanted to change the framework to use .Net and C# but use the same Database. The passwords created by the spring security are encrypted. I wanted a way to validate the username and password using the same database.

Is there a way to do this ?

EDIT :

I have read a couple of posts on SHA decryption. Is there another way to deal with it ?

Comment: Hopefully the passwords are *hashed* and not *encrypted*. The difference being the first is not reversible, which is an important difference. You can surely implement the same algorithm surely on .NET but it will require manual work.

Comment: Yea I have done some research and it seems to be the only way. I will post my findings .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to look into form of encryption you use with spring security I haven't had to delve this deep into it but this may help

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/7f09c528bedcf53ff9d109dad725d68a54d36a2e/src/docs/passwords/salt.adoc

SystemWideSaltSource and Custom SaltSource

Spring Security supplies a simple SaltSource implementation, `{apidocs}org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/SystemWideSaltSource.html[SystemWideSaltSource], which uses the same salt for each user. It’s less robust than using a different value for each user but still better than no salt at all.

An example override of the salt source bean using SystemWideSaltSource would look like this:

Listing 1. Configuring SystemWideSaltSource as the saltSource bean in application.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SystemWideSaltSource

beans = {
   saltSource(SystemWideSaltSource) {
      systemWideSalt = 'the_salt_value'
   }
}
```

To have full control over the process, you can implement the SaltSource interface and replace the plugin’s implementation with your own by defining a bean in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy with the name saltSource:

Listing 2. Configuring a custom implementation of the saltSource bean in application.groovy

```
import com.foo.bar.MySaltSource

beans = {
   saltSource(MySaltSource) {
      // set properties
   }
}
```

Also take a look in here to understand possibly take plugin into debug to work out how it is working:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/7f09c528bedcf53ff9d109dad725d68a54d36a2e/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/authentication/encoding

You need to test a salt algorithm test on two systems that use the same salt key - you should find on both systems they will then encrypt / decrypt in the same manner. (since they both have the same door key)

Anyhow for what it's worth you have already had spring security encrypt in a given way (that you have no overview of) and now is a little too late since they will all need to be - re-encrypted

This is if you did you test with same salt against two systems and most importantly had 1 test system configured with spring security using this salt and tested the result on your .Net C#  system first

Also i breezed through it and did notice something about default encryption being related to username - so that may give you a clue on how you could write something similar for other end (finding out what it used for its default key)

Comment: I will try this and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that - that's the point of keeping passwords hashed in DB. However, you can always calculate the hash by yourself and compare it to the value stored in your database.

Comment: Do you know how calculating the hash can be done?  I have read a couple of posts on SHA decryption(If that is what you are pointing at). Is there another way to deal with it ?

Comment: @Adds unsure if @dawid is talking about the right thing when he says `comparing hash ` you can compare the hash of a set of values. The whole point of encrypting the password is to minimise all attempts by any one hacking to decrypt that information.  Encryption is based on keys and in short you would need to ensure that the same identical process of encryption decryption exists on both sides http://www.thespringriver.com/simple-example-of-java-encryption-decryption/. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/

Comment: I didn't mean decryption, I meant encryption. When user enters a password you calculate SHA1/MD5 (or whatever you used in spring) hash and compare it to the hash that is already stored in your database. Cryptographic hash function is one-way by definition - there is no option to revert it (you can only guess the password based on hash if you have huge database of password-hash mappings).

Comment: @Vahid  is there a way I can use the same encryption , decryption in .Net C# for validation or LOGIN.